# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 PHP

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin, php7

Estoy teniendo un problema al visualizar mi página web, desarrollada en php.

El proyecto consiste en una tienda en línea y, específicamente, este proceso es agregar un producto al carrito. Al momento de refrescar la página me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/canvas_ink/cart.php on line 84

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/canvas_ink/cart.php on line 84
```

Ae aparece el mismo error por cada columna, cambiando únicamente el # de la línea, adjunto imagen:

[image: Adjunto imagen]

Este es mi código:

````
<?php 
    session_start();
    include './php/conexion.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
        // si existe se busca si ya estaba agregado ese producto
    }else{
        // creamos la variable de sesión
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            $nombre="";
            $precio="";
            $imagen="";
            $res = $conexion->query('select * from productos where id='.$_GET['id'])or die($conexion->error);
            $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
            $nombre = $fila[1];
            $precio=$fila[3];
            $imagen=$fila[4];
            $arreglo = array(
                'Id'=> $_GET['id'],
                'Nombre'=> $nombre,
                'Precio'=> $precio,
                'Imagen'=> $imagen,
                'Cantidad'=>1,
            );
            $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
        }
    }
?>
```
 <?php 
                     if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){ 
                        $arregloCarrito =$_SESSION['carrito'];
                    for($i=0;$i<count($arregloCarrito);$i++){
                  ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="product-thumbnail">
                      <img src="images/<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Imagen']; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                    </td>
                    <td class="product-name">
                      <h2 class="h5 text-black"><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Nombre']; ?></h2>
                    </td>
                    <td>$<?php $arregloCarrito[$i]['Precio']; ?></td>
                    <td>
                      <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                          <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    

                    </td>
                    <td>$<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Precio'] * $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad'];?></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
                  </tr>
                    <?php } } ?>
````

¿Alguna idea de cómo corregir esto?

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces esto:

```
        $arreglo = array(
            'Id'=> $_GET['id'],
            'Nombre'=> $nombre,
            'Precio'=> $precio,
            'Imagen'=> $imagen,
            'Cantidad'=>1,
        );
        $_SESSION['carrito']=$arreglo;
```

El carrito queda con un solo producto, más o menos así:

```
$_SESSION['carrito'] = [
    'id' => id_del_producto,
    'Nombre' => 'Nombre del producto',
    'Precio' => 123,
    'Imagen' => 'imagen_del_producto.ext',
    'Cantidad' => 1
];
```

Al hacer `count($_SESSION['carrito'])` vas a obtener 5, pero cada índice corresponde a id, nombre, precio, etc. del producto agregado y necesitas que el carrito sea un arreglo de varios arreglos con información de cada producto y, para poder actualizar, asociar por ID

```
$_SESSION['carrito'] = [
    id_del_producto_1 => [
        'id' => id_del_producto_1,
        'Nombre' => 'Nombre del producto 2',
        'Precio' => 123,
        'Imagen' => 'imagen_del_producto1.ext',
        'Cantidad' => 1
    ],
    id_del_producto_2 => [
        'id' => id_del_producto_2,
        'Nombre' => 'Nombre del producto 1',
        'Precio' => 234,
        'Imagen' => 'imagen_del_producto2.ext',
        'Cantidad' => 1
    ],
];
```

Para lograrlo, primero necesitas inicializar el carrito como un arreglo:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include './php/conexion.php';
    // Crear el carrito si no existe:
    if(!isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {
        // Inicializar como arreglo vacío
        $_SESSION['carrito'] = [];
    }
```

Después necesitas obtener y verificar ID del producto a agregar o actualizar (con asignación ternaria):

```
    // Si existe el parámetro en GET
    //    ? asignar valor,
    //    : de lo contrario, asignar valor por defecto (cero)
    $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
    // Validar ID:
    if($id <= 0) {
        die('ID de producto inválido');
    }
```

Ahora, si el producto ya está en el carrito, se puede acceder por su ID:

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'][$id])){
        // si existe se busca si ya estaba agregado ese producto
        // Actualizar cantidad
        $_SESSION['carrito'][$id]['Cantidad'] ++;
    }else{
        // Buscar producto en base de datos
        $res = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = $id") or die($conexion->error);
        // Validar que el producto existe
        if($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
            // Crear arreglo con datos del producto
            $producto = [
                'Id'=> $id,
                'Nombre'=> $fila[1],
                'Precio'=> $fila[3],
                'Imagen'=> $fila[4],
                'Cantidad'=>1,
            ];
            // Agregar producto a carrito con $id como índice
            $_SESSION['carrito'][$id] = $producto;
        }
    }
?>
```

Para recorrer y mostrar los productos dentro del carrito no va a servir el *for*, porque los índices no son consecutivos, sino ID de cada producto agregado; entonces, se usa *foreach* para recorrer por el índice asignado cada producto como arreglo:

```
            if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){ 
                // Recorrer por $id y arreglo de producto
                foreach($_SESSION['carrito'] as $id => $producto) {
              ?>
              <tr data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <td class="product-thumbnail">
                  <img src="images/<?php echo $producto['Imagen']; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                </td>
                <td class="product-name">
                  <h2 class="h5 text-black"><?php echo $producto['Nombre']; ?></h2>
                </td>
                <td>$<?php $producto['Precio']; ?></td>
                <td>
                  <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" value="<?php echo $producto['Cantidad']; ?>" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                

                </td>
                <td>$<?php echo $producto['Precio'] * $producto['Cantidad'];?></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">X</a></td>
              </tr>
                <?php } }
```

**Nota:** Cuando soluciones este tema, vas a necesitar tener acceso a ID de cada producto en el carrito, por eso agregué *data-id* en: `<tr data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">`